# HTAcces Rewrite Directory Format to Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am really struggling to understand how I can use htaccess / rewrite to change a url in the form [www.domain.com/home/](http://www.domain.com/home/) to [www.domain.com/index.php?route=home](http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=home). I thought I  cracked it, but the url shown in the browser also changed to show the query string. I wanted the displayed url to change along with rewrite.

I also wanted to redirect http to https. I see other websites achieve this (stackoverflow for example).

My current attempt is:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(\w*?)/?$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?route=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: What URL do you want to show in browser and what is it showing?

Comment: I would like the browser to display domain.com/home but go to domain.com/index.php?route=home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `http://` or `https://` in target Apache will always send a `R=302` flag to clients, forcing a full redirect.

Here, you actually need 2 separate rules:

1. `http -> https`
2. `Rewrite` rule to `index.php` for non-files and non-directories

Suggested .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test these rules.

Comment: Works perfect - thank you very much, this was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Written as per your samples. Also please clear your browser cache after placing these Rules into your .htaccess file. You are using `R=301` redirection which is why it changes the url to url of backend in browser itself, you don't need it.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @James, I too learnt from anubhava sir's post, http---> https redirection will change url for sure so we need 2 rules here, hence I changed it now, this should work now. You could try anubhava sir's answer too, let us know how these both solutions go, cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much - works great! I really appreciate your help with htaccess black magic!